# archimesh wall seperation

Tags: modeling, archipack-add-on

Alright, so I'm designing a tiny house for a friend using the archimesh add-on, so far it's worked out great. however as you'll see in figure 1. I'm trying to make some extra modifications to part circled in red, I created it by copying the top outer edges and separating them from the main wall, then extruding them to create that part of the roof, now id like to make some extra modifications using the wall menu, but the second I I play with the settings, it completely resets to the original wall it came from.

does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

fig. 1.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice this message? [image]

Did you try after applying modifiers? I think it works. Try it.

[image]

Comment: I have applied all of the modifiers, however it is still connected to the original wall.